# How to find the Date differenet with two date and exclude sunday

Tags: sql, datediff

```
DECLARE @totaldays INT, 
        @weekenddays INT, 
        @startDate datetime = '2023/01/01', 
        @endDate datetime = '2023/01/08'

SET @totaldays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) +1 
SET @weekenddays = ((DATEDIFF(WEEK, @startDate, @endDate) * 2) + 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate) = 1 
                            THEN 1 
                            ELSE 0 
                    END + 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @endDate) = 6 
                            THEN 1 
                            ELSE 0 
                    END)

SELECT (@totaldays - @weekenddays) AS Days
```

I have this code to find the `datediff` of 2 dates excluding 'Sunday'.

The result is 5, but it should be 6.

If @startDate datetime = '2023/01/01', @endDate datetime = '2023/01/07'
result = 6, the answer becomes correct.

How can I make it become the correct query?

Comment: on your first ``case`` you need to change it like this ``CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END``

Comment: Which dbms are you using? DATEDIFF is a product specific function.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to make this `CASE WHEN` construct correctly run, but in my opinion, this is really bad to read.
I would do following:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime
DECLARE @enddate datetime
DECLARE @count int

SET @count = 0
SET @startdate = '2023/01/01'
SET @enddate = '2023/01/08'

WHILE @startdate <= @enddate
  BEGIN
    IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@startdate) <> 1
      SET @count = @count + 1
      SET @startdate = DATEADD(d,1,@startdate)
    END
SELECT @count AS Days;
```

The simple idea is to use a counter which will be increased by one only in case the day is no sunday.

Try out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nNw4BbE7)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

*I have some small adjustment in your query*

```
DECLARE @totaldays INT,
        @weekenddays INT, 
        @startDate datetime = '2023/01/01', 
        @endDate datetime = '2023/01/08'

SET @totaldays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) +1 
SET @weekenddays = (select datediff(day,@startDate,@endDate) /7 +
case   
    when datepart(WEEKDAY,@startDate) = 1 then 1
    when datepart(WEEKDAY,@startDate) > datepart(Weekday,@endDate) then 1
    else 0
end)

SELECT (@totaldays - @weekenddays) AS Days
```

You can try it from here : https://dbfiddle.uk/vBYoOWW6